# UI-Bootstrap Datepicker Ignores ng-Change in Some Cases?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to understand why the Clear and Today buttons in the below plunker don't cause ng-change to fire.

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I can't use a $watch on my ng-model variable.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hw6fviimNdPJLu3IVit1?p=info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug that will be solved by https://github.com/bekos/bootstrap/commit/84e6736fb5f606988187c3caa802747ae0f1a270.

Cheers :)